# Zip Code Combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Please help ASAP!

Zip codes consist of five digits. How many zip codes read the same upside down as right side up?

The answer is $75$, but why? Shouldn't it be $3^5$ because $0$, $1$, and $8$ can be read the same upside down, and right side up?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it "ASAP"?

Answer (score 4):

**Hints**:

Normal strings are read left-to-right, but upside down strings are read right-to-left (w.r.t. the original orientation).  Thus, any zip codes containing only $0, 1$, and $8$ that are the same upside-down and right-side-up need to be palindromic, and from this notice that the first $3$ digits determine such a string.

Moreover, don't forget that a $6$ becomes a $9$ upside-down.  This means that the string $06890$, for instance, is read the same upside-down and right-side-up.

Comment: Why is it 75? Shouldn't it then be greater than $3^5$? I got 125, because the first slot has 5 options, so does the second and third.

Comment: The third slot only has three options: putting a $6$ or $9$ there doesn't work, so you're left with $0$, $1$, and $8$.

Comment: Indeed @DanUznanski . I was only talking about strings of $0, 8$, and $1$ in that first paragraph.  I didn't explicitly mention that point so the OP could fill in missing details as it looks like a homework problem.

Comment: @Jerry, you can't have arbitrary strings of $0,8,$ and $1$ since $10888$ is read as $88801$ upside-down, and these are not the same.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Got it!!!